# Cannot connect to remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Connecting from Windows 7 Home to Windows 7 Enterprise.

Done the following:

- port forwarding for 3389
- enabled RD in System properties
- connected to it with Teamviewer, so it's running
- allowed RD in Windows Firewall for private/public

This is still unsolved - thanks for all suggestions so far and any further help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here is a sort of summary for others.

`nmap` was used for examining RDP port state. http://nmap.org/

`Port Forwarding` and `Port triggering` was set on router for `port 3389`.

From internet it was stated as `closed`, meaning that we got response `icmp destination-unreachable`.

Windows by default is not responding, but silently drops packets, so nmap instead of closed would say `filtered`(as without response).

Reason was `Port triggering`, port wasn't triggered to open from lan. After disable `Port triggering`, port 3389 was open on router and nmap was showing `port filtered`.

It was caused by routers dhcp server, that assigned another IP address to Windows PC. So after wezten assinged IP to MAC address of computer with RDP, it just works.